# How is it possible to take the mean seperately for each year?

Tags: r

I want to find the mean of the stock return in Apple from 1981-2019, however I've got it monthy and need it to be yearly.

I've tried:

```
Mean_each_year <- aggregate(Apple[-1], format(Apple[1],"%Y"), sd, na.rm =TRUE
```

But I get an error:

> not in a list.

So how do I fix that?

Sample data:

```
         <dbl> <chr>                 
1     19801128 NA                    
2     19801231 C                     
3     19810130 -0.170018             
4     19810227 -6.1674E-2            
5     19810331 -7.5117000000000003E-2
6     19810430 0.15736
```

Comment: if you use aggregate, the "by" should be in a list. For example aggregate(Apple[-1], by = list(format(Apple[1], "%Y"), FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE). Personally I would specify the column with a name (such as Year and stock), and use the column names in aggregate instead of [1] and [-1]. Also, it seems that you specify the standard deviation in your function, not the mean

Comment: @maarvd the issue is that i have no idea how to do that, because i am a complete noob. Is there a step by step process i can do? ^^ thank you for the answer c:

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
      date     value
1 19810130 -0.075117
2 19810227  0.157360
```

First I create a year column

```
library(lubridate)
df$Year <- year(ymd(df$date))
```

returning

```
      date     value Year
1 19810130 -0.075117 1981
2 19810227  0.157360 1981
```

Then I aggregate by year

```
aggregate(df$value, by = list(df$Year), FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

returning

```
 Group.1         x
1    1981 0.0411215
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lubridate/dplyr solution

```
library(dplyr)   
library(lubridate)
 
 apple_stock <- tibble( #recreated your data, not sure what "C" is, so I made it NA
   date = c( 19801128, 19801231,19810130, 19810227,19810331, 19810430),
   value = c(NA, NA, -0.170018, -6.1674E-2 , -7.5117000000000003E-2, 0.15736 )
   )
 
 apple_stock %>% #(If you're new to this, '%>%' is a pipe, passes objects through to the next argument)
   mutate(year = year(ymd(date))) %>% #create the year variable. Used lubridate's 'ymd' function to convert to date, then the 'year' function to extract the year
   group_by(year) %>% #group by year
   summarise(value = mean(value)) #take the mean for each year
```

Output:

```
    # A tibble: 2 x 2
   year    value
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1  1980    NaN  #NaN since there are no numeric values in 1980   
2  1981   -0.0374
```